# Site age and the number of visits are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

According to [Stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites), this site is 2013 years old, but sadly has 0 visits/day.

[image: site list]

Comment: I know this has come up before.  I want to say it's a caching issue...

Comment: Visits should refresh soon on their own. We had to set up a new property in Google Analytics and it simply has no data yet.

Comment: I never knew the statistics on that page were fetched from Google Analytics.

Comment: Just the visits, @AmalMurali. And it's cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visits are still gonna take a while to catch up (we show median visits over two weeks and MSE is a baby site), but they'll get there. The age has also been fixed up.